# How to add custom password reset template for Parse app hosted on Parse?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, cloud, hosting, reset-password

I have a web application that I am hosting on Parse with a subdomain "appname".parseapp.com url (The quotes are not actually there, and that's not the actual link to my app). Supposedly, I am able to use my own templates for things like the password reset form, however, I haven't had any success. I downloaded the template, modified it, and put it in my public directory then deployed it. I set the Parse Frame URL to the "appname".parseapp.com/user_management.html like it says after also putting the user_management.html file in my public directory, then I set the directory of password reset file in the Customize User-Facing Pages section as choose_password.html since it is right in the public directory. The link sent to the email that attempts to reset the password somehow keeps being wrong and gives me a 404. I'll get a link like this: "appname".parseapp.com/user_management.html?link=%2Fapps%2Fschool-project%2Frequest_password_reset&token=TvIoEhOD8ZsWAP414jBCbY3OI&username=testuser

Any Idea why this isn't working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my mistake. I was supposed to include the entire link for the template not just the directory after the domain. e.g. "appname".parseapp.com/choose_password.html rather than just /choose_password.html